# vnstat rx and iftop rx mismatch

Tags: linux

First, I run the vnstat -tr -i eth0 and iftop in two shell at the same time. It's strange that the rx in vnstat is very larger than the peak rx in iftop. How can I fix this problem?

### Rx in vnstat

```
5679980 packets sampled in 5 seconds
Traffic average for eth0
rx  530.52 Mbit/s      1130727 packets/s
tx   49.88 Mbit/s         5258 packets/s
```

### Rx in iftop

```
TX:             cum:  205MB         peak:  47.1Mb
RX:                   10.9MB               9.30Mb
TOTAL:                217MB                52.2Mb
```

Answer (score 0):

Dude, RX in vnstat uses MegaBit(**Mbit**); while iftop uses MegaByte(**MB**). They have different measurement, of course the result won't be the same.

**1 byte = 8 bit**

You can get more information about "Mbit vs MB" in google. Just search it.

Comment: Thanks! Rx in iftop (peak:  9.30Mb), I think this is MegaBit. Our bandwidth is total 50Mb.